# IIS 10 - Windows Authentication error - Cannot login some user!

Tags: iis, windows-server-2016, windows-authentication, iis-10

I've a IIS 10 service on a Windows Server 2016 in the domain.
There is a website with Windows Authentication.
The rule monitors that the incoming user is a member of the AD\xy group or not.
If member of the AD\group, then the user is can login into the website.

Problem:
Some user is can login, some user is cannot login to the website, from the same computer!

Here is the web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument enabled="true">
            <files>
                <remove value="Default.htm" />
                <remove value="Default.asp" />
                <remove value="index.htm" />
                <remove value="iisstart.htm" />
                <remove value="index.html" />
                <add value="index.html" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        
        <security>

            <authorization>
                <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
                <add accessType="Allow" roles="AD\xy" />
            </authorization>
        </security>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="http to https redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: How many groups are they in?

Comment: The users? Who cannot login 7 and 10 and who can login like me: 20